# Setting the Most significant sign bit(Lint warning)

Tags: c, lint

Im working on a function where i have to convert a 3 byte array and return the 3 byte array as a single int32.
The code is as follows:
pbData is a pointer to the byte array.

```
const byte bMSBitPosNeg = 0x80;
const byte bMSBNeg = 0xFF;
int32 i32Num = 0;

//Big - Endian
if (pbData != NULL)
{
    if ((pbData[0] & bMSBitPosNeg) == bMSBitPosNeg) //Negative
    {
        i32Num |= (bMSBNeg * 0x1000000); //Force MSB to 0xFF as 3 bytes are 
                                        //converted to 4 bytes
    }

    i32Num |= (pbData[0] << 16);
    i32Num |= (pbData[1] << 8);
    i32Num |= (pbData[2]);

}
return i32Num;
```

Input : {0x00,0xBB,0xA3}
Output: 48035 //positive number

Input : {0xff,0x44,0x5d}
Output: -48035 //negative number

The code works as expected, but i get a lint warning. 
Warning 648: Overflow in computing constant for operation: 'multiplication'

I need the functionality but dont want the warning.How do i suppress it?

Comment: use `UL` suffix on your `0x1000000` constant

Comment: If you do the multiplication as the corresponding shift, would it make sense then? Remember that you're working with `int` which is a **signed** 32-bit type (on most platforms).

Comment: A general tip: When working with bits, *always* use explicitly unsigned data types.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in this case it's desired to return a negative value in some cases so it's not simple

Comment: @M.M I would still recommend using unsigned types for the actual bit-fidling, then cast it to a signed type when needed.

Comment: OP, can you confirm how negative numbers are represented in your byte stream? E.g. are they using 2's complement

Answer (score 2):

You can replace multiplication with bit shifting, or even compute the bit pattern manually for better readability:

```
const int32 bMSBNeg = (int32)0xFF000000;
```

You can also avoid all these computations by constructing the number in the upper three bytes, and then shifting it down by 8 bits with division:

```
if (pbData != NULL) {
    i32Num = ((pbData[0] << 24) | (pbData[1] << 16) | (pbData[2] << 8)) / 256;
}
```

**Note:** shifting by 8 instead of dividing by 256 would be implementation-defined behavior according to the standard.

Comment: Your first line is an out-of-range assignment (there are a few issues here in unpacking negative values; if OP wants to avoid implementation-defined behaviour then we're going to have to be careful)

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators 5 The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. [...] If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.*

Comment: @EOF Oops, the pesky standard with its implementation-defined behavior got me again. I should use division by 256 instead.

Comment: I'd consider a caveat like "on sane implementations" good enough, but your solution is better.

Comment: @EOF Yeah, OP's whole approach relies upon "sane implementation" - even setting FF in the upper byte relies on two's complement representation. It would break on sign-and-magnitude platforms (which are almost entirely imaginary these days, but standard writers must pretend that they exist).

Comment: const int32 bMSBNeg = 0xFF000000; "Warning 569: Loss of Information(32 bits to 31 bits)"

Comment: pbData[0] << 24 ; "Info 701: Shift left of signed quantity(int)"

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD Shifting signed numbers left is fine. That's why this isn't even a warning.